# How to pass parameters between JNI and DLL files implemented by C++

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, native

the following code is declared in JAVA

```
private native static Vector< Double > computeSimXML(Vector < String > vDocsPath);
```

I want to pass the parameter vDocsPath ( defined as Vector < String >) into C++, the code generated by JNI is as follows:(I have implemented some)

```
/*
 * Class:     SimXMLModule
 * Method:    computeSimXML
 * Signature: (Ljava/util/Vector;)Ljava/util/Vector;
 */
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_SimXMLModule_computeSimXML
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jobject)
{
   vector<double>  dist;

   dist.push_back(5.0);
   dist.push_back(6.0);

}
```

How can I get the value of `vDocsPath` through  `jobject`, and return dist ( defined as `Vector< Double >` in JAVA) to JAVA?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a good function for starting with JNI - implementing it correctly will take some work.

- The `Vector<String>` parameter is a plain non-generic `Vector` runtime.
- The `Vector<Double>` return value is a plain non-generic `Vector` runtime
- You need to retrieve class and method IDs, and call `Vector` functions to get data out of the parameter
- You need to construct a series of `Double` objects, set the internal `double` and call `Vector` methods to setup the return value.

I'd recommend you changed the function signature to:

```
private native static double[] computeSimXML(String[] vDocsPath);
```

The JNI interface for working with arrays is a *lot* simpler than what you're trying to do. You can iterate over parameters with `GetArrayLength` and `GetObjectArrayElement`, and you can create and manipulate the return value with `NewDoubleArray`, `GetArrayElements` and `ReleaseArrayElements`